# Sql Error - #1293 - Incorrect table definition;

Tags: sql

Created a table with `CreationDate` and `UpdationDate` columns. The error reported is that only one column can be of type `TIMESTAMP` and use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. What is the proper syntax?

[Image from MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W4qm.png)

```
    create table tbladmin (
    id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    AdminUserName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    AdminPassword VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    AdminEmailId VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Is_Active INT(11) NOT NULL,
    CreationDate timestamp NOT NULL  DEFAULT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
    UpdationDate timestamp NULL ON UPDATE 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
    ) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

Error message from MySQL:

`#1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only on TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause`

Comment: Please enter the table definition directly instead of posting an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `CreationDate` and `UpdateDate` columns to be of type `datetime()` instead of `timestamp`.